# Anchor tags are not showing up in the document

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

Anchor tags are not showing up in the document
We have a 14 page document where the users will have to sign at the end of the Document on the field specified. The Document pdf looks like '

[image]

Where near the By field I have `/s1/` tag which is invisible. And also in the Docusign custom button Controller I have the code like

```
    ................
    Attachment att = [Select id,Name,Body,parentid from Attachment where parentid =: OppLst.id order by createddate DESC LIMIT 1 ];

DocuSignTK.Document document = new DocuSignTK.Document();
document.ID = 1;
document.Name = 'Quote Document';
document.FileExtension = 'html';
document.pdfBytes = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attach.Body);

DocuSignTK.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignTK.Recipient();
recipient.Email = 'dh@gmail.com';
recipient.UserName = 'Dh';
recipient.ID = 1;
recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;

// The signer tab...
DocuSignTK.Tab signHereTab = new DocuSignTK.Tab();
signHereTab.Type_x = 'SignHere';
signHereTab.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignTK.AnchorTab();
signHereTab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'signer1sig'; 
signHereTab.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 8;
signHereTab.RecipientID = 1;
signHereTab.Name = 'Please sign here';
signHereTab.ScaleValue = 1;
signHereTab.TabLabel = 'signer1sig';

// The dateSigned tab
DocuSignTK.Tab dateSignedTab = new DocuSignTK.Tab();
dateSignedTab.Type_x = 'DateSigned';
dateSignedTab.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignTK.AnchorTab();
dateSignedTab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'signer1date';
dateSignedTab.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = -6;
dateSignedTab.RecipientID = 1;
dateSignedTab.Name = 'Date Signed';
dateSignedTab.TabLabel = 'date_signed';

// Create an envelope and fill it in
DocuSignTK.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignTK.Envelope();
envelope.Subject = 'Please sign the Quote Document'; 
envelope.AccountId = account_id;
envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfTab();
envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignTK.Tab[2];
envelope.Tabs.Tab.add(signHereTab);
envelope.Tabs.Tab.add(dateSignedTab);
envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfRecipient();
envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignTK.Recipient[1];
envelope.Recipients.Recipient.add(recipient);
envelope.Documents = new DocuSignTK.ArrayOfDocument();
envelope.Documents.Document = new DocuSignTK.Document[1];
envelope.Documents.Document.add(document);

if (String.isNotBlank(email_message))
{
 envelope.EmailBlurb = email_message;
}
```

In the Docusign email it doesn't show anything
[image]
How to make the tags available so it is easy for the user to click and Sign.

Answer (score 0):

the string that you use in your document to "anchor" the tabs should be the same that you specify in your tab AnchorTabString property.

You mentioned that the document has an invisible `/s1/` tag in the text, but it looks like in your code you are setting a different value for the anchor string:

```
signHereTab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'signer1sig';
```

if you update this value to match the `/s1/` value in your document it should work.

One way to troubleshoot this would be to log into your DocuSign account, create a new envelope using the document above, add a recipient and go to the tagger page.

Once in the tagger page you can use the "auto-place" feature, which is the same as the anchor strings, to test that the string that you want to use as an anchor can be found in the document.

Once you verify that you have the right string, you could use that string in your API call and things should work.

How to use the auto-place feature:
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience